# confluent control center launch button under connector tab is not working

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-control-center

The confluent control center is up and running, I was able to configure the JDBCsource connector under the connect tab....before the test and verify screen where it shows the final Json which looks something like , I am clicking on the launch button but nothing happens. Is this a UI problem on do I need to add more property while setting up the connector

{

```
"key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://kafka1:8081",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://kafka1:8081",
  "name": "Test",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/connect_kafka",
  "connection.user": "user",
  "connection.password": "password",
  "table.whitelist": [
    "confluent_connect"
  ],
  "mode": "timestamp",
  "timestamp.column.name": [
    "load_ts"
  ],
  "validate.non.null": false,
  "topic.prefix": "mysql"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Connect REST API directly, without Control Center.

This will let you verify success without relying on clicky-clicky actions.